# JTextArea not appearing on JScrollPane when building through methods

Tags: java, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am trying to make a class in which I can create a JFrame by calling different methods to build upon it. However somewhere along the lines my JTextArea is getting lost...

Below is a class called App which holds the methods I need to start building...

```
public class App {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    public void openJFrame(String title, int x, int y){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setSize(x, y);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public JFrame getJFrame(){
        return frame;
    }
    public void addJTextArea(JScrollPane scrollPane){
        scrollPane.add(textArea);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setVisible(true);
    }
    public JTextArea getJTextArea(){
        return textArea;
    }
    public void addJScrollPane(JFrame frame){
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    }
    public JScrollPane getJScrollPane(){
        return scrollPane;
    }
```

I would like to call this class from my main method and build a JFrame. Below is my attempt.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        App app = new App();

        app.addJTextArea(app.getJScrollPane());
        app.addJScrollPane(app.getJFrame());
        app.openJFrame("title", 500, 500);
    }
```

What happense is the JFrame and ScrollPane appear.. however my text area doesnt seem to be adding to the scroll pane.

Am I misunderstanding or overlooking something? It may be worth noting that if in the addJTextArea method I add it directly onto the JFrame without using the JScrollPane method it appears (obviously without the scroll pane)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `JScrollPane` may look/act/sound similar to a `JPanel`, it is not. And thus, using `JScrollPane.add()` to add a component to the scroll pane may sound natural, but is wrong. `JScrollPane` can only have one component inside that it scrolls around, and thus `add()` is wrong, but `setViewportView()` is the method to use.

You have to adapt your method `addJTextArea` to use `scrollPane.setViewportView()` instead of `scrollPane.add()`:

```
public void addJTextArea(JScrollPane scrollPane){
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    textArea.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `scrollPane.add(textArea);` with `scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);`.

For more details read [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)